# how to build reponsiveApp example of extjs 5.0.1 using sencha cmd

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

How to build A RessponsiveApp Example of extjs 5.0.1 using cmd http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/responsive-app/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Sencha Cmd, you can run `sencha generate app` to scaffold the basic application architecture.

You would then use various other commands (`sencha app build`, among others) to compile your app along the way, build your theme, etc.

The responsive design bits however are dependent on YOU -- you have to explicitly tell your app which parts need to be responsive, and more importantly, what they need to do in those situations. Check out the [blog post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/designing-responsive-applications-with-ext-js/) and [webinar](http://www.sencha.com/blog/optimizing-your-ext-js-apps-for-touch-and-tablets/) from Sencha discussing this topic.